# Why does the getInputStream() method of HttpURLConnection return an object of type RealBufferedSource?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm attempting to send an HTTP request from an `AsyncTask` in Android Studio, using the code below.

```
protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urls[0].openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.connect();

        byte[] loginRequestBytes = new Gson().toJson(loginRequest, LoginRequest.class).getBytes();
        connection.getOutputStream().write(loginRequestBytes);

        if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            ResponseBody responseBody = (ResponseBody) connection.getInputStream(); // ResponseBody extends InputStream
            loginResponse = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody.toString(), LoginResponse.class);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("HttpClient", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

My `ResponseBody` class extends `InputStream`, so I thought that using

```
ResponseBody responseBody = (ResponseBody) connection.getInputStream();
```

would work, but here is the problem:

I'm getting a `ClassCastException` in my code, because `connection.getInputStream()` returns an object of type `com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1`. Why is `getInputStream` not returning `InputStream` as per [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URLConnection.html#getInputStream())? Is this an android-specific issue?

**EDIT:** I defined the ResponseBody class myself (shown below). It is **not** the one from `okhttp`, and it does extend `InputStream`, as far as I can tell.

```
public class ResponseBody extends InputStream {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this, "UTF-8"))) {
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this may help u **[Understanding getInputStream and getOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22563986/understanding-getinputstream-and-getoutputstream)**

Comment: **FYI** the `HttpURLConnection.getInputStream()` returns an **`InputStream`**

Comment: "My ResponseBody class extends InputStream, so I thought that using." -> Which response body are you referring to? This one - https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html. This does not extend InputStream per the documentation. Would you like to take a look at this page: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection

Comment: @RakeshRoy I actually defined the ResponseBody class myself. It is a simple extension of InputStream (see edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getInputStream()` method *does* return an `InputStream`.  But you are attempting to cast the result to a `ResponseBody`.  That won't work unless the result object is an instance of a subtype of `ResponseBody` ... which it isn't.

Now, it is unclear which `ResponseBody` class you are trying to use here, but if it is `okhttp3.ResponseBody` ([javadoc](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/class-use/ResponseBody.html)), then you can't obtain it by casting an `InputStream`.

---

> I actually defined the `ResponseBody` class myself. It is a simple extension of `InputStream` (see edit), so I seems like the downward cast should work

Ah.  I see.

No that won't work.  You cannot cast an object to a type that it isn't.  That's not what type casts do ... for reference types.

You have an instance of the anonymous inner class

```
  com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource$1
```

which is a subtype of `InputStream`.  You are trying to cast it to a `ResponseBody` which is also a subtype of `InputStream`.   But `ResponseBody` is NOT a superclass or interface of the anonymous class, so the typecast cannot succeed.

I suggest that you rewrite `ResponseBody` to be a wrapper class for `InputStream` and / or use one of the solutions listed here fro extracting the contents of an `InputStream` to a `String`:

- [How to read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-to-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually defined the ResponseBody class myself. It is a simple extension of InputStream (see edit), so I seems like the downward cast should work